# Как посчитать кол-во вхождений одной строки в другую?

Tags: python, python-3.x

С клавиатуры вводятся две строки. Найти количество вхождений одной (являющейся подстрокой) в другую.
Пример1: s = 'saddassad', t = 'sad'
Результат1: 2
Пример 2: s = 'qeqeqeq', t = 'qeq'
Результат2: 3

```
s = input()
t = input()

def suffix_counter(str, sufix):
    if len(str) < len(sufix):
        return 0



suffix_counter(s, t)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Просто используйте метод `count`. Позволяет найти подстроки любой длины в строке.
Пример:

```py
print('030302'.count('03'))
>>> 2
```

Примечание: таким же способом можно посчитать количество вхождений элемента в список, но не слайса, как в случае со строкой:

```py
print([0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 2].count(0))
>>> 3
print([0, 3, 0, 3, 0, 2].count([0, 3]))
>>> 0
```